# Why Google Chrome developer tool's source search is so slow now?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

I am not sure if I am the only one, but about couple months back, the Google Chrome Inspector's source search (Cmd + Alt + F) is extremely slow for large web application (big source file). It usually before took around 2~3 sec, now it takes at least 1~2 min! I found out though, somehow the search got speeded up quit a bit when the code is at a stop point, and I start search code. But it is not a sustainable solution, and tedious while not working all the time. My Chrome version is 54.028.

Comment: I have the same problem. Started about 6 weeks ago. For me it works the 1st time I run my app (1-2 sec per search). But if I spend some time debugging and then do the same search, it takes forever ... I can't take it the wait, so I try to kill the browser tab. Can't do it!  You have to go to task manager and kill everything. Pretty strange. I switched to useing MS Edge to get work done.

Comment: Same for us!  Our product has tons of JavaScript so searching is a must, but sometimes I have time to get a cup of coffee.  I personally will switched to Edge myself for this reason, but prefer to have options, especially when debugging IndexedDB or other bits that Chrome is better at.

Comment: https://crbug.com/680205, https://crbug.com/661912, https://crbug.com/669533

Answer (score 2):

This has been a [known problem](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=624097) in Chrome for a while now. Switching to [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) should fix the problem.

Comment: Yes! Canary seems to have resolved this problem for me. But it wasn't until after the Feb 24 release. I guess there were a couple of rounds of fixes:  https://crbug.com/680205

Comment: I tried canary with Vue, no better, this is not a valid fix.